# Need to load an appropriate master page for an error page

Tags: asp.net

We have implemented two master pages, parent master page (without menu) and child master page (with menu). Whenever any error occurs throughout the website, we redirect the request to the error page. Some of our website pages are configured with the parent master page and remaining with the child master page. The error page is a common page where we would like to identify the requester page and it’s master page. So that, the same master page can be configured dynamically on error page.

There is one way specified on MSDN blog about Accessing Members on the Master Page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.ASPX), but I did not try implementing it yet due to following query.

1. Where should I define the query string "color" parameter? Do I need to change the request URL? I cannot change it for an error page of our website as error page in itself is internal page. Please advise.
2. I read the comments after the post, and it seems like the things are not working as specified in the post. Please clarify.

Additionally, I tried with this.PreviousPage.MasterPageFile, but it is null in my case.

Any other possible solution. 
Can anybody also response me on the queries that I put on the above post?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: You should remove that URL and instead copy over the pertinent content to this question so we aren't relying on a link that may become broken over time. Once you do that, we will need to know what code you've tried so far.

Comment: Can anybody help me on above master page problem?